# The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists

Tags: magento-2.3

I am trying to save and duplicate the product in Magento 2.3 and I get the following message:

**The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists.
To resolve this conflict, you can either change the value of the URL Key field (located in the Search Engine Optimization section) to a unique value, or change the Request Path fields in all locations listed below:**

I tried creating the custom module to override doReplace function of DbStorage.php file.

Theses are the files
module.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Urls_FixUrls" setup_version="1.1.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

registration.php

```
    <?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Urls_FixUrls',
    __DIR__
);
```

di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\Storage\DbStorage"
                type="Urls\FixUrls\Model\DbStorage" />
</config>
```

DbStorage.php

```
    <?php
namespace Urls\FixUrls\Model;

class DbStorage extends Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\Storage\DbStorage
{
    protected function doReplace($urls)
    {
        foreach ($this->createFilterDataBasedOnUrls($urls) as $type => $urlData) {
            $urlData[UrlRewrite::ENTITY_TYPE] = $type;
            $this->deleteByData($urlData);
        }
        $data = [];
        $storeId_requestPaths = [];
        foreach ($urls as $url) {
            $storeId = $url->getStoreId();
            $requestPath = $url->getRequestPath();
            // Skip if is exist in the database
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM url_rewrite where store_id = $storeId and request_path = '$requestPath'";
            $exists = $this->connection->fetchOne($sql);

            if ($exists) continue;

            $storeId_requestPaths[] = $storeId . '-' . $requestPath;
            $data[] = $url->toArray();
        }

        // Remove duplication data;
        $n = count($storeId_requestPaths);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $n - 1; $i++) {
            for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $n; $j++) {
                if ($storeId_requestPaths[$i] == $storeId_requestPaths[$j]) {
                    unset($data[$j]);
                }
            }
        }
        $this->insertMultiple($data);
    }
        
}
```

After setup upgrade and cache clean I try to access any product it gives me message saying

 **magento.local is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500**